# How to add a column to continuous transform in pipelinedb

Tags: pipelinedb

There are many continuous views, two continuous stream and a continuous transform in the same schema.
Now, I want to add a column within `varhcar` to one of the streams and the transform.

Add column to stream is no problem, but when drop continous transform, then create the transform is error.
Error notice is stream must have the same shcema as the transform.
Why and how to do this?